# How to add mouse events to the drawing object in Java?

Tags: java

In my program, at the beginning I want the ball to be stagnant and start the action when the mouse is clicked.

What method do I need to follow?

I tried following:

```
 public class Ball extends Applet implements Runnable{

        int x=200;
        int y=450;
        int dx=10;
        int dy=10;
        int r=30;
        private Image i;
        private Graphics graph;
        @Override
        public void init() {

            setSize(500,500);

        }

        @Override
        public void start() {
            Thread t1=new Thread(this);
            t1.start();

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

           while(true){
               if(x+dx>this.getWidth()-r){
                   x=this.getWidth()-r;
                   dx=-dx;
               }
               else if(x+dx<0){
                   x=0;
                   dx=-dx;
               }
               else{
                   x+=dx; 
               }
                if(y+dy>this.getHeight()-r){
                   y=this.getHeight()-r;
                   dy=-dy;
               }
               else if(y+dy<0){
                   y=0;
                   dy=-dy;
               }
               else{
                   y+=dy; 
               }
               repaint();
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(50);
               } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
        }



        @Override
        public void stop() {

        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            //double buffering
            if(i==null){

                i=createImage(this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
                graph=i.getGraphics();
            }

            graph.setColor(getBackground());
            graph.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            graph.setColor(getForeground());
            paint(graph);
            g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void paint (Graphics g){

            g.setColor(Color.PINK);
            g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add a Mouse Listener, in your case you can check the method mousePressed or mouseClicked

Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

You can create your MouseListener `MouseListener ms = new MouseListener();`
it will generate the methods of the MouseListener, then you just have to modify the one that you want ( mousePressed or mouseClicked ), to finish do not forget to add the MouseListener to the object that you want to be listened `object.addMouseListener(ms);`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14430918)

Comment: This is a much better answer now. By the way, it's typically not required to include 'Edit: ' when you modify your post on SO, unlike some other sites, so I've edited that out for you, but you should be out of the Low Quality Posts filter now you've improved the post.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new to this website, I prefer that somebody tells me when I make a mistake